# Querying a range in fromObject

Tags: angular

I'm using a dynamic form with 4 options and you can use any combination of options. 2 are looking for string matches and 2 are looking for a number value within a certain range(gte, lte). The first 2 work fine if used alone but I'm having trouble with the numbers within a range. I appreciate any help and if there is a better approach I'm all ears.

If I use all options my form creates an object like this example

```
{
 brand:"Stamps",
 fins:"fcs-2",
 volume:{$gte:26.6, $lte:31.6},
 length:{$gte:65, $lte:76}
 }
```

This is sent as an argument to here

```
getFilteredBoards(searchParams): Observable<Board[]> {
const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: searchParams });
return this.http.get<Board[]>(this.surfSwapUrl, { params });
}
```

The query string being produced looks like this

```
 /boards?brand=Stamps&fins=fcs2&volume=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&length=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

So as you can see the brand and fin part is working correctly but volume and length are not coming acoss correctly. Is the nested volume and length objects what's causing the query string to be wrong? Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Its converting the volume and length arguments to a string in the URL. The string for a JS object is "Object [Object]" which is exactly what you are getting. You cannot use an object in a URL, pass the object properties individually.

You might also consider using the popular [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) npm module, which handles nested objects, where you can do things like:

```
var qs = require('qs');

const obj = {
  brand:"Stamps",
  fins:"fcs-2",
  volume:{$gte:26.6, $lte:31.6},
  length:{$gte:65, $lte:76}
}

qs.stringify(obj);
// returns brand=Stamps&fins=fcs-2&volume%5B%24gte%5D=26.6&volume%5B%24lte%5D=31.6&length%5B%24gte%5D=65&length%5B%24lte%5D=76
```

Comment: Ok great. I was under the impression that with Angular's fromObject you could pass it an object and it would convert it because if I pass it  just {brand: "Super"} it will create the right query string. I must've misunderstood something somewhere along the line. Anyways qs looks awesome! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

volume and length are objects but you can't send an object as a queryParam